# POST and Navigate in Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using BLAZOR Razor Component. I want to use Navigation Manager to transfer data (a JSON string or model data) from the Razor component to the MVC Controller via the POST method.

I have tried

POSTJSONASYNC Method but Navigation Manager Work Seperateltly. My Requirement is to Transfer the data with Navigation Manager in POST Method.

Comment: `NavigationManager` class cannot be used to send POST http request. You need to use `HttpClient` class.

Comment: Could you please tell me why you wan to use Nagigation manager do post request?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75516347/rdlc-report-download I want to download the RDLC from the razor component to MVC Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can not transfer data(make request) using NavigationManager. You need to use `HttpClient` to request from blazor to API.

For more understanding you can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

Simply using a classic `<form action="your/controller" method="post">` with a call to `form.submit()` by javascript could work. Obviously the data will be in formdata, but you could have a hidden field containing your json.