# RDLC Report Download

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Unable to Download the RDL Report By Calling the Function in Razor Component

Razor Component

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ModelNAME);
var response = http.PostAsJsonAsync("GenerateReport/AdmissionReport/pdf",json).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

MVC Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("GenerateReport/{myReportName}/{ReportExtension}")]
        public IActionResult index(string myReportName, string ReportExtension, [FromBody] string JsonString)
        {
            try
            {
                string path = $"{_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath}\\Reports\\";
                int ext = (int)(DateTime.Now.Ticks >> 10);
                string mimetype = "";
                Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
                Encoding srcEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
                Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                List<Mdl_AdmissionReport> rpt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Mdl_AdmissionReport>>(JsonString);
                LocalReport lr = new LocalReport(path + "ReportName.rdl");
                lr.AddDataSource("myDataSet", rpt);
                parameters.Add("ReportParameter2", "ParameterNAME");
                var result = lr.Execute(RenderType.Pdf, ext, parameters, mimetype);
                return File(result.MainStream, "application/pdf", myReportName + ".pdf");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Can not download the File

By using the Razor Component i want to download the RDL Report from Razor Component

Comment: Have you debugged? could you show  where you got the error and what's the error message

Comment: No Error Shown...Code Executes Properly

Comment: Do not use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, just `await` that.

Comment: If "...Code Executes Properly" then you should have a download. Always document the errors in full.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download a file from blazor server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57327440/how-to-download-a-file-from-blazor-server-side)